# Pandas and matplotlib doing linear graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Any idea whats missing in my code to avoid part of the graph/canvas and dates being out of the PNG image? Is it possible to have the dates written in 180 degrees or in vertical to not use so much space of the grapth?

My data set is:

```
15/03/16    3000    300 200
12/04/16    3000    300 300
10/05/16    500 500 400
12/06/16    1000    600 500
14/07/16    1250    300 500
21/07/16    2000    300 50
15/08/16    3000    300 200
12/09/16    3000    300 300
10/10/16    500 500 400
12/11/16    1000    600 500
15/11/16    1250    300 500
21/12/16    1000    500 50
```

Python code is:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';', 
                     index_col=0, 
                     parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                     names=['date','a','b','c'])
df.plot()
df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(6, 6))

plt.savefig('sampledata1.png')
```

And png looks like (missing data):

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is there, it is just being plotted on the edge of the plot. You can change the y-limits globally with

```
df.plot(ylim=(0,3500))
df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(6, 6), ylim=(0,3500))
```

To change them for each plot, I think you'll need to plot the curves individually.

To do it individually, I typically do something like this (there are a zillion ways do it):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)
axes[0].set_ylim([df.a.min()*0.9, df.a.max()*1.1])
axes[0].set_xticklabels([])
axes[1].set_ylim([df.b.min()*0.9, df.b.max()*1.1])
axes[1].set_xticklabels([])
axes[2].set_ylim([df.c.min()*0.9, df.c.max()*1.1])
axes[0].plot(df.a)
axes[1].plot(df.b)
axes[2].plot(df.c)
```

[image: jupyter screenshot]

The axis labels can be adjusted to be readable, etc. - checkout matplotlib.org for lots of examples.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So how could I do it individually for each plot? thanks again.